# Anyone know a code editor I can embed in a WPF window or Windows forms?

Tags: wpf

I want create my own IDE but I want a code editor that would
syntax highlighting.

I want to embed it as a control into a WPF window.

Malcolm

Answer (score 36):

The [Sharp Develop IDE](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop) has a great code editor that can be used in your programs relatively easily (it does require a little bit of work to figure out how it works, and it doesn't have "plug and play" documentation).  If you look at the source for [Kaxaml](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/kaxaml) you can see how to embed it in WPF.

Answer (score 27):

If you do not mind having no documentation whatsoever, [AvalonEdit](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Default.aspx?Page=AvalonEdit&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) is a good choice. I am currently using for a project, and it is a great tool. I have not encountered a single bug even in complex scenarios.

You can find its source at svn://svnmirror.sharpdevelop.net/sharpdevelop/trunk/SharpDevelop/src/Libraries/AvalonEdit.

Comment: Andrey, where is the source code for AvalonEdit? I browsed sharpdevelop.net but didn't find any links to AE's source code

Comment: You can find it at svn://svnmirror.sharpdevelop.net/sharpdevelop/trunk/SharpDevelop/src/Libraries/AvalonEdit. I am not sure if there is a http browser for sharpdevelop sources, but TortoiseSVN works just fine.

Comment: I found a great guide for AvalonEdit here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor

Comment: There's now full documentation on the publisher's website: http://avalonedit.net/documentation/

Answer (score 10):

Another option is Scintilla.NET (**UPDATED** https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET).

It is a .NET 2.0 wrapper around the Scintilla Native Control. We have successfully used to display/edit HLSL, XML, Text, and other internal scripting languages. It is easy to write a language description file for your own language if needed.

I'm currently hosting the WinForms control in our WPF applications. The only difficulty was getting a WPF context menu to activate when clicking within the control; solved it by listening for a MouseRightButtonDown event on the WinFormsHost and then setting the ContextMenu visible (ContextMenu.IsOpen = true) :/

I have been in contact with Actipro Software re: SyntaxEditor and the WPF version is being actively developed and will available soon. For the time-being we will continue to use Scintilla.NET