# Silverlight XML editor / syntax highlighting

Tags: silverlight, editor, controls, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for a **Silverlight text editor control** that provides **XML syntax highlighting**. I found a few answers in *Winforms* or *WPF*, like [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394751/anyone-know-a-code-editor-i-can-embed-in-a-wpf-window-or-windows-forms), but I didn't manage to convert them to Silverlight. The fact that Silverlight is missing System.Drawing is probably a big problem.

The only text editor I found for Silverlight is [RichTextEdit on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/richtextedit), but I don't think it is a suitable base for real-time syntax highlighting.

Has anyone heard of such a control, or can provide hints on how to build one?
Many thanks,

Romain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found that control I was looking for!
[SL2TextBoxWsSynParser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SL2TextBoxWsSynParser.aspx)

EDIT: This control does not seem to be updated anymore, but a new syntax-highlighting control has surfaced:

It is available [here](http://www.vladhorby.com/Blog/post/2010/05/05/Syntax-Highlighting-TextBox-in-Silverlight-using-MVVM.aspx), and used on the [CoderProof](http://www.coderproof.com) website.

Comment: An updated version can be found here: http://www.vladhorby.com/blog/post/2010/11/01/code-editor-control-with-syntax-highlighting-for-silverlight-available.aspx . It now supports various languages (C#, VB.NET, XML, etc)

Answer (score 4):

Actipro Software has a syntax highlighter component for Winforms, WPF, and Silverlight:

http://www.actiprosoftware.com/

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was an interesting question, but you've had no answer.

I don't know of an existing control.

I've built a control to edit XHTML, but it too uses System.Drawing rather than WPF (and therefore isn't for Silverlight).

WPF is probably at least as capable as System.Drawing, but I don't know it.

Hints on how I built it:

- Define a DOM (a vanilla System.Xml.XmlDocument might suit you)
- Parse a document to instantiate a DOM
- Define a user control (with scroll bars)
- Pass the DOM instance to the user control
- In the control's 'paint' method, paint the visible fraction of the DOM
- Implement support for mouse and key presses

If you really want hints on how to build one, ask something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Hi & thanks for your answer!

Unfortunately, while WPF has drawing capabilities, Silverlight runs a very restricted set of the CLR. Painting the user control looks like quite a difficult task.

However it has been done before with this [Rich text editor for Silverlight](http://www.codeplex.com/richtextedit). I will see if I manage to use similar techniques to render the XML document.

One question though: is the user control fast enough to render the DOM on the fly, as the user makes changes?