# Silverlight control with code hightlighting?

Tags: silverlight, controls, syntax-highlighting

Is there a Silverlight control out there that will allow you to type in text and have it highlighted as code?

For example:

```
foreach (client in Clients)
{
   client.Save();
}
```

would become

```
foreach (client in Clients)
{
   client.Save();
}
```

I need to write a web app to screen [non-programming programmers](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/02/the-nonprogramming-programmer.html) without wasting time on them one by one.  I am thinking of a Silverlight app that will ask a few simple programming questions with a time limit.  After the limit is up, it will send what they have via a web service.

Most of that is quite doable for me, but I would like to be able offer my candidates code highlighting.  I am not up to (nor interested in) writing a Silverlight code highlighter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411913/silverlight-xml-editor-syntax-highlighting

Comment: Oh, and look at http://www.coderproof.com/

Comment: @andyp - coderproof looks nice, but I am looking for (and writing) something much less interactive.  The idea is to just have them do the questions (in a time limit) and submit the result.  Then we can evaluate them (and then can take the test) when we (they) have time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actipro Software has a syntax highlighter component for Silverlight, WPF, and Winforms:

http://www.actiprosoftware.com/

Answer (score 1):

In Silverlight4 you could use the RichTextArea control.

The link below has some info on this control:
http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-richtextarea.aspx

Still in Silverlight 4 you can also use the HTML brush.

In Silverlight 3 you can also show HTML but using a third party control. The one below is free.
http://www.divelements.co.uk/silverlight/tools.aspx

There are also those articles on syntax highlighting:

http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2010/06/06/Code-Syntax-Highlighting-in-Silverlight.aspx
http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/03/syntax-highlighting-text-block/
http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/theprogressbar/archive/2010/05/12/silverlight-rich-text-edit-control-custom-syntax-highlighting.aspx