# Silverlight: Is it possible to syntax-colour XML in a textBox?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, silverlight, pretty-print

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Silverlight XML editor / syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411913/silverlight-xml-editor-syntax-highlighting)

Hello,

I have some XML in my Silverlight Application that I store in a `String` and wish to output to the user. The xml is already "pretty printed" in the sense that it is formatted with indentations, but it would make it much clearer to read if I could also add syntax colouring to it.

Can this be done? How do I go about doing it? (please suggest a library or something)

Come to think of it, I'm not even sure if it's at all possible to output coloured text in a .NET interface...

Thank you for any insight!

(PS: I don't care which version of Silverlight)

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411913/silverlight-xml-editor-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked and did not find a control that would do XML syntax highlighting for a WinForms RichTextBox.  This was for an XPath evaluator tool I built.  The WinForms RichTextBox has the capability to display colors of course, but I couldn't find one smart enough to highlight XML syntax.

I ended up building one.  The approach I used would probably work for WPF as well.

[image]

This is the explanation for how I got there:
[WinForms RichTextBox : how to reformat asynchronously, without firing TextChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457411/winforms-textbox-how-to-reformat-asynchronously-without-firing-textchanged-eve/1462625#1462625)

Comment: Although I don't have time right now to implement this sort of thing myself, it's definitely something I will be trying out when I get a vacation. Thanks! It'll come in handy.