# Syntax Highlighter for WPF

Tags: wpf, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I'm currently looking for a Syntax highlighter for a WPF application.  A textbox will be available for the user to type into which would hopefully recognise code and highlight syntax accordingly.

I would like to support C# initialy and other languages later.

Duplicate of Question [394751](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394751/anyone-know-a-code-editor-i-can-embed-in-a-wpf-window-or-windows-forms)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind having no documentation whatsoever, [AvalonEdit](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Default.aspx?Page=AvalonEdit&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) is a good choice. I am currently using for a project, and it is a great tool. I have not encountered a single bug even in complex scenarios.

Comment: It is in the svn://svnmirror.sharpdevelop.net/sharpdevelop/trunk/SharpDevelop (do not remember the exact path), source only (but very easy to build).

Comment: It has a handy nuget package as well. I found it extremely easy to integrate into my application (for simply displaying highlighted color in read-only fashion). 2 minute job.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing without success. Only solution I found is Actipro's [Syntax Highlighter](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WindowsForms/SyntaxEditor/default.aspx) for WinForms that can be hosted in WPF application. AFAIK Actipro is working on WPF version but I don't know if it ready or not