# format string in textblock as c# code

Tags: c#, wpf

In my wpf application, I have a requirement to format the textblock to show code snippet. Is there anything out there that already does this?

So return VSConstants.S_OK; should in the textblock show up as,

[image]

Comment: _Syntax highlighting_.

Comment: Syntax highlighting, that's the word.

Comment: Sharp Develop is open source and includes an extended WPF RichText control with support for syntax highlighting, code folding, etc.

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454872/syntax-highlighter-for-wpf

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Very useful pointers, i'll explore these avenues. I am certainly looking for a syntax highlighting solution, that i can extend for my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try this control:

http://syntaxhighlightbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1. That control looks much simpler and quicker to implement than the SharpDevelop control. I have bookmarked it!