# syntax highlighting in a lightswitch textbox

Tags: textbox, visual-studio-lightswitch, syntaxhighlighter

Does anyone know how to add syntax highlighting in a lightswitch textbox?
I suspect it does not exist, so does anyone have any suggestions where to start if I would like to add the feature?

Comment: This problem is a combination of problems already solved. [LightSwitch client controls are Silverlight controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674919.aspx). Combine that with answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394751/anyone-know-a-code-editor-i-can-embed-in-a-wpf-window-or-windows-forms) and you should get it to work. If you work it out **please post an answer**.

Comment: That will work! I will post the solution if I get it up and running.