# A C# Equivalent of the ACE syntax highlighter

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Anyone know a code editor I can embed in a WPF window or Windows forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394751/anyone-know-a-code-editor-i-can-embed-in-a-wpf-window-or-windows-forms)

I am looking for a good C# equivalent of the HTML/JavaScript syntax highlighter ACE, found here http://ace.ajax.org. I am open to any approach - a component, a library - it needs to be WPF; it would be great if it could support C like languages, html, css etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for a control for WinForms or WPF ?